# ReactJS - State change is not observed in divs wrapped in sub component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react class. In it I'm using other react components. I'm new to React so I think I'm misunderstanding how state scope works. When menuClicked() is called, the outermost div's class will change but the innermost div's class does not. Can someone explain why?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Row from '../components/grid/Row.js'
import Cell from '../components/grid/Cell.js'

export default class HeaderBar extends Component {

    state = {
        menuOpen: false
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.menuClicked = this.menuClicked.bind(this);
    }

    menuClicked() {
        this.setState({menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen})
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className={`header-wrap ${this.state.menuOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}
            >
                <Row>
                    <Cell
                        c={1}
                        mc={12}
                    >
                        <div className={`platform-name ${this.state.menuOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}>The Platform Name</div>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell>
                       <div onClick={this.menuClicked}></div>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Added by popular demand

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Row extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.children = props.children;
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="r">
                    {this.children}
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And the Cell class

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Cell extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.props = props;
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className={`c${this.props.c}`}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code for `Cell` in case that's somehow preventing an update.

Comment: Also, it might be important to note what is calling `menuClicked()` since that's not in the code as posted.

Comment: I guess `Row` as well if the problem isn't in `Cell`.

Comment: I've added everything requested, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in Row component constructor, you do `this.children = props.children;`, then you render `this.children`.

Remember constructor is called only once. So `this.children` is assigned once with initial value and never get updated afterwards. It’s a stale reference!

Don’t do that, just render `this.props.children`

Comment: And the same with `Cell`

Comment: You are a scholar and a saint! Thank you!!